# How to determine if a realm exists and has data in it

Tags: android, gridview, realm

In the realm example

[ealm-java/examples/gridViewExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmgridview/GridViewExampleActivity.java](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/gridViewExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmgridview/GridViewExampleActivity.java)

The code always deletes the contents of the existing realm (if present) and then inserts new example data. How would you change that example to determine if the sample data (or any data) was already present in the realm - and to use the realm data instead of recreating a new realm? 
I am used to sql, realm looks exciting but I am having issues getting my head around some things such as this.

Thanks in advances to anyone who can help me get this sample working so it does not delete the realm data each time, once that is in place I can continue learning, by doing ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you remove the line that says `Realm.deleteRealm(config)` and then check if the Realm is empty with:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
realm.isEmpty(); // true if no objects are in the Realm
...
```

That should do what you want.